# Structure Scrapy Spider to Returning Scraped Data as a CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am able to get the scraped information returned in a readable format in the vscode terminal, but when I try and for mat the code into a csv it only returns one line of information. I take this to mean that its not iterable, but I'm not sure what to change to make it iterable.

I think the problem comes when I yield the response.follow to the parse_page function because without it everything works fine, but I still need to get the info from the second page.

Its possible that I have to create the dataframe outside the whole thing, and create a list of all the items outside the RusCodSpider class and then create the CSV, but I'm not sure where to start or how to do that.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd 
import os
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from googletrans import Translator, constants
from pprint import pprint


class RusmodSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ruscod'
    allowed_domains = ['test.ru']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        print('')
        print('*'*25)
        f_block = input("What is the f number of the page you want to scrape?: ")
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://function.test.ru/news/country.htm?f={}&blk=10322350&objInBlock=25'.format(f_block), callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'})

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath("//div[@class='newsitem']")
        for x in container:
            doc = x.xpath(".//span[@class='date']/text()").get()
            title = x.xpath(".//a[@target='_self']/text()").get()
            rel_url = x.xpath(".//a[@target='_self']/@href").get()
            
            abs_url = 'https://function.test.ru/{}'.format(rel_url)

            # keywords to flag
            for x in title.split():
                if x == "учение" or x == "учения" or x == "условного" or x == "учении" or x == "двустороннего":

                    yield response.follow(url= abs_url, callback= self.parse_page, meta= {'doc' : doc, 'title' : title, 'abs_url' : abs_url})

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = []
        translator = Translator()
        doc = response.request.meta['doc']
        title = response.request.meta['title']
        abs_url = response.request.meta['abs_url']

        district = response.xpath("//a[@class='date']/text()").get()
        last_line = response.xpath("//p[@style][last()]/text()").get()
        
        trans_title = translator.translate(title, src='ru')
        trans_dis = translator.translate(district, src='ru')
        trans_last_line = translator.translate(last_line, src='ru')

        for x in trans_last_line.text.split():
            if x == "involved":
                trans_last_line = trans_last_line
            else:
                last_line = "n/a"
        
        
        item = {
                        'date_of_creation' : doc,
                        'title' : trans_title.text,
                        'url' : abs_url,
                        'district' : trans_dis.text,
                        'participation' : trans_last_line.text
                    }
        items.append(item)
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = ['title', 'date_of_creation', 'url', 'district', 'participation'])
        cur_datetime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H%M')
        os_dest = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'Desktop', 'Russ CoD{}'.format(cur_datetime))
        yield df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(os_dest))




process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(RusmodSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas instead of Scrapy’s [feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)?